# Computing module of complex power

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$$
  |n^{i b}| 
  = |e^{i b  \log(n)} |
  = |e^{i b  (\ln(n) + i \operatorname{Arg}(n) + 2 k \pi i) } |
  = |e^{i b  (\ln(n) + 0 + 2 k \pi i) } |
  = |e^{i b \ln(n) - 2 k \pi b } |
  = |e^{ - 2 k \pi  b } | \,.
$$
Can this be more simplified? I found somewhere that the modulus is then equal to $1$. Can someone give an explanation why it is equal to $1$? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with complex logarithms is that they don't always satisfy the identities you expect of them that were valid on the real line. Indeed, your reasoning is vaild as stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Applications), but you won't find $1$ unless you use the principal branch ($k = 0$).